# How to return a named tuple with only one field

Tags: c#

I wrote a function in c# which initially returned a named tuple.
But now, I only need one field of this tuple and I would like to keep the name because it helps me to understand my code.

```
private static (bool informationAboutTheExecution, bool field2thatIdontNeedAnymore) doSomething() {
        // do something
        return (true, false);
    }
```

This function compile. But It's the following function that I want

```
private static (bool informationAboutTheExecution) doSomething() {
        // do something
        return (true);
    }
```

the error messages:

> Tuple must containt at least two elements

> cannot implcitly convvert type 'bool' to '(informationAboutTheExecution,?)

Has somebody a solution to keep the name of the returned value?

Comment: what exactly is your use for a one-element named tuple?

Comment: This sounds like an opportunity for a `out` parameter instead...

Comment: You could just make it a regular function and return a bool instead of a tuple, and add XML documentation comments to the code describing what the return value represents.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes but maybe I will add another field to this tuple later. But thanks it's a good idea

Comment: Although .NET allows for single-element tuples, C# does not, as there's no way to make the syntax unambiguous and the usefulness is dubious.

Comment: One option is to create a `DoSomethingResult` class or struct and return that instead and then just update it whenever you need to return more values.  You can even add deconstruction to it so that it will be similar to a value tuple.

Comment: @juharr Can you deconstruct to a 1-tuple though?

Comment: @Sweeper No, because of the reason Marc mentions in his answer, but presumably they like to get the result and do `result.informationAboutTheExecution` otherwise doing something like `var (success, field2) = something();` (when it was a tuple) defeats the purpose of having that name in the tuple.  Alternatively when it's just one value you can add an implicit cast which would be as close to a 1 value tuple deconstruction as you can get.

Comment: Imo, the main issue is that `if(x>y)` will be invalid syntaxe if `(true)` was a single value tuple. And even if you don't consider `if`, you will have ton on issue on every expression wrapped in parentesis: ` 2×(3 + 4)` You can multiply Singl-Uple int right ?

Comment: I want this syntax to exist, as it is simply logical.  Why are (a,b) and (a,b,c)... and so on all valid, and not (a)?  I know it does not seem a big deal and yes there are zillion alternatives, but elegance and consistency mean alot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just want to add another option, althought he `out` is the easiest workaround and Marc explained already why it's not possible. I would simply create a class for it:

```
public class ExecutionResult
{
    public bool InformationAboutTheExecution { get; set; }
}

private static ExecutionResult DoSomething()
{
    // do something
    return new ExecutionResult{ InformationAboutTheExecution = true };
}
```

The class can be extended easily and you could also ensure that it's never null and can be created with factory methods like these for example:

```
public class SuccessfulExecution: ExecutionResult
{
    public static ExecutionResult Create() => new ExecutionResult{ InformationAboutTheExecution = true };
}
public class FailedExecution : ExecutionResult
{
    public static ExecutionResult Create() => new ExecutionResult { InformationAboutTheExecution = false };
}
```

Now you can write code like this:

```
private static ExecutionResult DoSomething()
{
    // do something
    return SuccessfulExecution.Create();
}
```

and in case of an error(for example) you can add a `ErrorMesage` property:

```
private static ExecutionResult DoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        // do something
        return SuccessfulExecution.Create();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // build your error-message here and log it also
        return FailedExecution.Create(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what we used to do when tuples were not a thing at all, and in terms of extensibility it's still hard to beat (adding fields will not break existing callers, unlike with tuples).

Comment: As an aside, very simple classes like this (which are typically immutable) are also prime candidates to be implemented as `record`s where available (i.e. `record ExecutionResult(bool InformationAboutTheExecution) { public static ExecutionResult Success { get; } = new(true); }`. This gives you some goodness like comparison for free.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot, basically. You can return a `ValueTuple<bool>`, but that doesn't have names. You can't add `[return:TupleElementNamesAttribute]` manually, as the compiler explicitly does not let you (CS8138). You could just return `bool`. You *can* do the following, but it isn't any more helpful than just returning `bool`:

```cs
    private static ValueTuple<bool> doSomething()
        => new ValueTuple<bool>(true);
```

Part of the problem is that `({some expression})` is already a valid expression *before* value-tuple syntax was introduced, which is why

```cs
    private static ValueTuple<bool> doSomething()
        => (true);
```

is not allowed.

Answer (score 6):

If you must name your return, you can do this:

```cs
private static void doSomething(out bool information) {
    // do something
    information = true;
}
```

then call it with

```
bool result;
doSomething(out result);
```

Comment: or just `bool doSomething()` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell That's not "naming your return" is it?

Comment: @MarcGravell: That's OP's problem, he wants a name for this bool and the method-name is not enough, because it does not describe the bool but what the method does. The `out` parameter is the perfect workaround.